# Geocoder not working with "Geocode from another field"

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to make Geocoder work but encountered the following issue:
I installed Geocoder 7.x-1.2, and I want to use it with content from another field, namely   Location 7.x-3.0-rc2. I installed Leaflet to try to display my nodes. When I create new nodes, the Geofield is not filled in anymore(it remains empty whatever the address I try to use). I installed Address Field 7.x-1.0-beta4 instead of Location  but the same issue persisting.

When I create new nodes this is the error message I got :

```
Undefined index: default_value in geofield_field_presave() (line 281 of /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/contr/geofield/geofield.module) 
Notice: Undefined index: geom in geofield_field_presave() (line 293 of /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/contr/geofield/geofield.module).
```

Are there common issues that would make the geocoding fail? If not, is there a procedure to try to debug this?

Comment: Use the latest (dev) versions of all modules and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be solved by installing the other version of [geofield](https://drupal.org/project/geofield) module Geofield 7.x-2.0-beta1 (don't use the 7.x-2.x-dev version).

Answer (score 2):

What I don't like with the Geocoder module is the "magic" it does - how it automagically geocode values and relate to other fields, while actually all it needs to do is its own task - geocode...
This is why I developed the [Geocoder Rules](https://drupal.org/project/geocoder_rules), and the action that takes value, use geocoder, and return value.
I really like Rules, and think using it creates real value for any Drupal site. I think the way Commerce uses Rules is another proof that this method actually works.
I recommend you will try it out, and I will be happy to help if needed.
While it still doesn't have a "stable" release, it actually works well (as far as I can tell), and I plan to get decent with it soon...

I also [wrote a little](http://shushuinbar.blogspot.co.il/2013/02/reverse-geocoding-in-drupal-7.html) about it before in my blog...
Good luck,
Shushu

Comment: when I save the location the following notice displaying Notice: Undefined index: default_value in geofield_field_presave() (line 281 of /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/contr/geofield/geofield.module)
Notice: Undefined index: geom in geofield_field_presave() (line 293 of /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/contr/geofield/geofield.module). Is there any problem in the module?

Comment: I don't know this specific error. Do you use the dev version of the geofield module ? I think you should, since it is a fast pacing development...

Comment: No I am not using the dev version

Answer (score 0):

for me what solve the problem using dev release 7.x-2.x-dev 2013-Aug-31